# jQuery add class when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When i click one of the buttons i want the paragraphs to change size depending on the button i've clicked. That doesn't seem to work. I've checked everything and with my level of knowledge of jQuery (beginner ) i can't figure it out so i need your help. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="smaller" value="smaller text" />
    <input type="button" id="bigger" value="bigger text" />
    <p > Some text inside of it.</p>
    <p > Some text inside of it too!</p>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="query.js"> </script>
</body>

</html>
```

jQuery

```
$('#bigger').click(function() {
    $('p').addClass('.bigger');
});

$('#smaller').click(function() {
    $('p').addClass('.smaller');
});
```

CSS

```
.bigger {
    font-size:30px;
    background-color:red;

}
.smaller {
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `.` from `addClass()` because the function already recognize the string like a class without specifiy the class selector.

try this:

```
$('#bigger').click(function() {
    $('p').addClass('bigger'); //instead of .bigger
});

$('#smaller').click(function() {
    $('p').addClass('smaller'); //instead of .smaller
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6yR6s/)

Comment: You should explain why this is the answer. For example: **.addClass()** accepts a string parameter of one or more space separated classes. It does not accept a selector.

Comment: accept The answer to help other guys with your same problem @user3638147

Comment: I don't know how to do that, i'm new to the site :) @AlessandroMinoccheri

Comment: click behind the number of vote on The left of my answer@user3638147

Answer (score 1):

Remember `$.addClass("bigger");` not `$.addClass(".bigger");`

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/ebGQ2/